# Search for different tables with multiple words

Tags: php, search, mysqli

I have a form

```
<form action="buscar.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
</form>
```

And my page where they show the results

```
<?php
 require_once 'meekrodb.php';
 $q = $_GET['q'];
 $results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE description like '%$q%'");
 foreach ($results as $row) {
  echo $row['name']."<br>";
 }
?>
```

For example I have these phrases in `description`:

```
My car is big and green
My house is small and green
```

When I look for `green`, the 2 results come out, but if I look for a `green house` nothing comes out.

The problem is that I have to search for continuous text to work for example... `My house is small...`

**How can I improve this query? Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Try to explode `GET` variable.Or you can try to play with `CONCAT`

**Explode**

```
$q = $_GET['q'];
$word_array = explode(" ",$q);
$sqlnames="SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE";
$count = 0;
foreach($word_array as $value){
if($count == 0){
    $sqlnames .= " description LIKE '" . $value ."'";
}
else{
    $sqlnames .= " OR description LIKE '" . $value ."'";
}
$count = 1;
$sqlnames .= " OR description LIKE '" . $value ."'";    
}
$sqlnames .="LIMIT 20";
```

**CONCAT**

(something like that)

```
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM product_description WHERE description LIKE '%$q%' OR description LIKE '%$q%' OR CONCAT(description, ' ', description ) LIKE '%$q%' LIMIT 20");
```

I have not tested this, but you can try to play.